# Hide Request/Response header for get request from fiddler or other apps

Tags: api, security, fiddler, mobile-application, charles-proxy

I need to get request from android app Im using Memu emulator
I installed xposed and sslunpinning
when i use proxy with burp suit or fiddler
the app not conneted !!
how can I fix this problem

Comment: Your question should be improved because it is not clear what is your environment. Maybe you are not sending the traffic to burp suite... With that info we can not give you a good answer...

Comment: sslunpinning module seems to be a bit old. Last time I used an unpinning module I used [TrustmeAlrady](https://github.com/ViRb3/TrustMeAlready). If that does not help the app may not use Java based TLS code, and use own native code. Alternatively for on app you can also use Frida+Objection which has some unpinning scripts (doe snot require xposed).